# C# MSBuild Conditionally Compile Project to not Include Partial Class referencing Nuget

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I have a simple `netstandard2.1` library that references a Nuget and has a partial class that Nuget is referenced. I want to essentially have the class compile down to 2 DLLs, one with the Nuget and partial class included, and one without.

I've made a simple example here to showcase this:
https://github.com/aherrick/ConditionalCompilation

What MSBuild sorcery do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the file containing the partial class is not enough because as I see in your example the `Location` property is referenced in other necessary files.

It may not be the cleanest solution but I had the same need and resolved using the preprocessor:

```
#ifndef EXCLUDE_VENUE_LOCATION
    public partial class Venue
    {
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public Geometry Location { get; set; }
    }
#endif
```

And the same in Program.cs

```
#ifndef EXCLUDE_VENUE_LOCATION
    venue.Location = null;
#endif
```

Then to conditionally set globally the define with **msbuild** you can compile as:

```
msbuild /p:DefineConstants=EXCLUDE_VENUE_LOCATION solution.sln
```

Comment: thanks for the help here. I've given this a go but not having much success. would you be able to do a PR?

Comment: i've updated my code

Comment: Using `#if` instead of `#ifndef` inverts the logic, in your case normal compilation will exclude the class and the parameter `/p:DefineConstants=EXCLUDE_VENUE_LOCATION` will include it.

Comment: how do i pass that parm at the project level?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">               <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)EXCLUDE_VENUE_LOCATION</DefineConstants> </PropertyGroup>`

to your project file. Condition attribute is optional/as needed.
It is not sorcery, but another way MS has chosen to input params to the command line of msbuild.

You can define or name a build configuration that lets you know that the nuget package is included or not.

BTW, msbuild runs a number of other pre-build files to verify everything in your project is kosher, and provide upstream project management. These are "*.targets" files.

Comment: hi thank you. not having much success. can you show with the code example i provided?

Comment: The full dissertation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022

Comment: Look at the tags and reproduce them exactly. Copy verbatim. You just added a Properties tag.

Comment: From what I see, you want to conditionally include a reference to the NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ package in the base project. It is from that project  you will want to produce two different Configuration outputs - one for consumption with and one without the package. So in the ItemGroup, add Condition="$(Configuration)" attribute.

Comment: What makes more sense is to simply separate out any code that needs access to the nuget package into a separate project. You then have two libs, one that has "shared" code, and one that references the nuget package.

Comment: i can't separate as I want the same class (Venue) to be reused

Comment: I see. Then you'll obviously need two different outputs from your base project. For that, conditionally include the package for one of the two.

Comment: I think I'd still go with two separate projects if possible. One with shared code, one without. Perhaps you could accomplish this using inheritance on the Venue class. Have a class VenueExtended : Venue that adds or overrides a Location property. Instantiate one or the other as you see fit.

Comment: If you do this, you won't have any conditional defines.  It is the simplest solution, and easiest to maintain.

Comment: FYI I ended up using inheritance and it's working great for what I need. Thanks!